# Making a Windows phone 8 like constant size tile in a JavaFX application

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

I'm making a WP 8 simulator using `JavaFX`. I have styled Buttons to look like tiles with CSS and I've used `setText()` for the name and `setGraphic()` for the icon.

To make it look like a real WP 8 tile, the text must be bottom-left aligned and graphic center aligned. How do I do that?

I've used `setAlignment()`, but that gives same alignment to graphic and text.
And `setTextAlignment()` doesn't work for single line text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert it in the css file,like this:

```
-fx-alignment: CENTER;
-fx-text-alignment: BOTTOM-LEFT;
```

Comment: -fx-alignment will align the button wrt the parent node which in this case is the background of my startscreen.
I want to align the graphic wrt to the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

which will align the entire content of the button (if there is extra space available for such an alignment to be necessary), and

```
setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);
```

which will align the graphic relative to the text.

Both of these can be set in CSS, using `-fx-alignment: center;`, and `-fx-content-display: top;`, if you prefer.

Comment: That will align both, the text and the graphic in the center. I want the text to be bottom-left aligned.

Comment: @RoystonD'mello Maybe `Pos.CENTER_LEFT` for the alignment? I can't test right now... If not you may need to use a `VBox` with two labels, one for the graphic and one for the text.